# Elastic search use range aggregation upon term aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

My question in SQL format is quite simple but I can translate it into elastic aggregation format

assume I want the result of blew query in elastic search

```
SELECT Foo.Type,COUNT(*) FROM Foo GROUP BY Foo.Type HAVING SUM(Foo.Price) > 20 AND SUM(Foo.Price) < 25
```

is there any aggregation combination in elastic which response to queries like these?

and it's important to mention the result of the first group (Foo.Type) is more than max elastic aggregation size (10000)

my data is:

---

ID    Type    Price

1     Blue    10

2     Blue    10

3     Blue    5

4     Red     15

and my result should be something like this:

---

Blue    3

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "byType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "price_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "price_bucket_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                          "totalPrice": "price_sum"
                        },
                        "script": "params.totalPrice > 20 && params.totalPrice< 25" 
                    }
                }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply but as I said it should return only result of last aggregation(use result of inner aggregation to aggregate upon it)

Comment: bucket filter will return you only required buckets. can you post what result you are actually getting & how this deviates from required.